# Sitecore Cache from Standard Value

Tags: templates, caching, sitecore

One sublayout (.ascx) is using datasource from its template standard value.
Whenever I enable the cacheable setting with `varyByData` and `varyByParm`, I can't get all field values in `__Standard Value` of its template.

I checked `cache.aspx` page and it shows:

```
**web[standardValues]________0________0________0________10MB<br />
MaxSize is 10MB, but zero Count, zero Size and zero Delta information.**
```

Any ideas of how to solve this?

**=============Update=============**

I have fields in a template for CSS class names, such as h1, ul class, etc ... and all names initially set in its "__Standard Values". 
Then, I have an item which calls the template's standard values as data-source.

This is another my post and it will help you more.
[Sitecore Cache Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044574/sitecore-cache-issue)

Could I know what the problem is?

**=============Update 2=============**

Current .cs file to get field values.

```
<asp:View ID="viewNormalMode" runat="server">
    <nav class='<% Response.Write(myDataSourceItem.Fields["Nav Bar Class"]); %>'>
        <h1 class='<% Response.Write(myDataSourceItem.Fields["Label h1 Class"]); %>'>
            <i class='<% Response.Write(myDataSourceItem.Fields["Label i Class"]); %>'></i>
            <% Response.Write(myDataSourceItem.Fields["Nav Bar Label"]); %>
        </h1>
    <ul class='<% Response.Write(myDataSourceItem.Fields["ul Class"]); %>'>
        <asp:Literal ID="linkObjects" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</asp:View>
```

Comment: Sorry Jay, but this question seems not to be complete enough to help you. Can you please edit your question to be a bit more specific? We need more information.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the some more information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand correctly.

How Sitecore Cache work on sublayouts: Let take a main navigation (as sublayout) when you enable the cacheable setting global or from page to page you will get this result: 
How your navigation looked at first page access after AppPool restart or application DLL update will look the same way on all other pages having cache on sublayout (even if you use another data source or something else, the code is cached/not executed).

But I think you have another bigger problem, move your fields for selection from Presentation Sublayouts on Data Template (Items) you will have huge problems on Locales. Beside you can add from code your classes as this:

You know your Layout, case you are in it, and you know you Context Item or your page definition  Item, base on template name `(Context.Item.TemplateName == "Article"`) put your CSS  classes

Comment: I have updated code information. I called each fields like myDataSourceItem.Fields["Nav Bar Class"]. 
Do I have to call the template first and retrieve all fields?

Comment: Your code is really messy, still let fix it. In page_load of your user-control define public Item myDataSourceItem = your selected item; Use Like this in markup:<h1 class='<%= myDataSourceItem["Label h1 Class"]); %>'>

Comment: Because of "<% Response.Write(myDataSourceItem.Fields["Label h1 Class"]); %>", it shows error??
I will test it and let you know the result. Thank you!